# Создаю атрибуты в Woocommerce, но они не видны в разделе "Атрибуты"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Создаю товар в WooCommerce и атрибуты к нему.  Все нормально, но я не вижу новых атрибутов в разделе "Атрибуты".

```
function create_product() {
    $product = new WC_Product_Simple();

    $product->set_name( 'Название товара' );
    $product->set_regular_price( '100' );

    // Добавляем атрибуты "бренд" и "цвет" к товару
    $attributes = array(
        'Бренд' => 'Ямаха',
        'Цвет' => 'Красный'
    );
$wc_attributes = array();
    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $attribute_value ) {
        $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
        $attribute->set_id( 0 );
        $attribute->set_name( $attribute_name );
        
        $attribute->set_options( array( $attribute_value ) );
        $attribute->set_visible( true );
        $attribute->set_variation( false );
        $wc_attributes[] = $attribute;
   
    }
$product->set_attributes( $wc_attributes );
    // Сохраняем новый товар
    $product->save();

    return $product->get_id();
}
```